# How to remove the same class from the same element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

On click I want to remove the same class from the same element which are located at diffrent div:

Here is the JS code.

```
$("#dialog").on('click',".selected_channel:not(.unselectable)", function(){ 
    $(this).removeClass("selected_channel");
    $("#item_container").find($(this)).removeClass("selected_channel");
});
```

Comment: your question is not clear, could you please elaborate more. Better take example and explain it. Please relevant provide HTML code also.

Comment: How are you searching for this "same element different div" item? By the same class? The same ID (they *should* be unique)? The same name? The same data attribute?

Comment: Here is the example https://jsfiddle.net/a6vhm67d/1/

Comment: The jsfiddle you have share has no html, no jquery library set and no explaination of problem at all. How will I help you?

Comment: You can download files here https://www.dropbox.com/s/9bwqpfim1c28lde/Duo.rar?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use class selector to locate the element

```
$("#dialog").on('click',".selected_channel:not(.unselectable)", function(){ 
    $(this).removeClass("selected_channel");
    $("#item_container .selected_channel").removeClass("selected_channel");
});
```

When you say `$("#item_container").find($(this))` it will return the the element referred by `this` only if it is an descendant of an element with id `item_container`

Comment: I need to remove that class only from that element. Because there can be more elements having that class...

Comment: @hasratyan sorry what do you mean... can you give the markup also

Comment: @hasratyan using `this` reference in another parent won't work as `this` is not a descendant of the other parent

Comment: Ok, now I will try to send

Comment: I tried to sent, but it has so long HTML/CSS/JS code, that makes impossible to send.. I'll try to describe it here.
Look. I have TV channels list. When I select an channel, it appears in basket (#dialog). On click on that channel it gets (.selected_channel) class. On second click it removes that class from that channel.
On basket when I click on that selected channel, it is hiding..
Now I want to remove that class from that channel from both sides.

Comment: what we are looking for is a sample of `selected_channel` element in `#dialog` and `#item_container`, don't need the entire page/css/script

Comment: Your code works. but it remove the `.item` from `#item_container`.. I need to remove `.selected channel` class from `.item`

Comment: There is one more question. Pls can you help?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/a6vhm67d/4/

Here I want to do the following.
If `item` dosen't have class `selected_channel`, then dont show in `#dialog`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/a6vhm67d/5/ - if it solved your would you mind marking the answer as accepted